# How do I combine these xpath expressions without using union (|) operator OR any other way to fetch the result?

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports

This XPATH query,I'm using in **Jasper iReport Designer**  with XML datasource

I have 2 XPATH expressions, Both are working individually perfect . But when using with union operator, its showing first page null, afterwards all data is valid and correct

```
/userQuestionAllocationResponse/questionnaireDetails/categoryDetails/categoryName | 
/userQuestionAllocationResponse/questionnaireDetails/listQuestionsAnswers
```

How do I write a single xpath expression that combines the two above 
and would return the same elements as running each of the expressions above individually?

Comment: Looking for the exact same thing. Were you able to solve it?